# Plot multiple columns of a data frame with a shared 'x'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe `df` as below (all columns numerical, but the last two should be categorical)

```
                 Close  Direction  prediction
Date
2018-03-31   40.889999         -1           1
2017-12-31   34.459999          1           1
2017-09-30   40.529999         -1          -1
2017-06-30   38.200001          1          -1
2017-03-31   43.160000          1          -1
2016-12-31   46.369999          1          -1
2016-09-30   63.180000          1          -1
2016-06-30   64.300003          1           1
2016-03-31   66.500000          1           1
2015-12-31   85.250000         -1          -1
2015-09-30   63.020000          1           1
2015-06-30   87.139999         -1          -1
2015-03-31   83.169998         -1           1
```

i want to plot these three columns with a shared x axis .

> plot1 - line plot (x = date index of dataframe , y = df[close])
>   plot2 - scatter plot (x = date index of dataframe , y = df[Direction])
>   plot3 - scatter plot (x = date index of dataframe , y = df[prediction])

all three plots should be one over the other sharing x axis,
I have tried the below core but is not getting desired output..

```
fig, (ax1, ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1,figsize=(10,7), sharex=True)
ax1.plot(x= df.index, y=df['Close'])
ax2.scatter(x= df.index, y=df['Direction'].astype('category'),color='blue')
ax3.scatter(x= df.index, y=df['prediction'].astype('category'),color='red')

xtick_dates = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq='3M')
plt.xticks(dates_rng, [dtz.strftime('%Y-%m') for dtz in xtick_dates], rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

can anyone find a way to solve this?

Comment: (1) `ax.plot()` does not have named `x` and `y` arguments. Hence `ax.plot(df.index, df["column"])` should work, but `ax.plot(x=..., y=...)` will not. (2) I don't think matplotlib will understand "category" type data. You can use strings instead.

Comment: tried both the changes, now i am getting the first plot , last two are missing with the labels, also the common x axis label

Comment: Concerning ticking, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35398327/matplotlib-date-manipulation-so-that-the-year-tick-show-up-every-12-months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured out

```
def plot_predictions(details):
    global path
    df = pd.read_csv(path+"Quarterly_prediction.csv",parse_dates=['Date'],index_col=0)

    fig, (ax1, ax2,ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1,figsize=(10,7), sharex=True)
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.2)

    ax1.plot( df.index, df['Close'])
    ax1.xaxis.grid(True,alpha=0.3)
    ax1.set_ylabel('Quarterly Closing')

    ax2.scatter(x= df.index, y=df['Direction'],color='blue')
    ax2.xaxis.grid(True,alpha=0.3)
    ax2.set_ylabel('Actual Direction')

    ax3.scatter(x= df.index, y=df['prediction'],color='red')
    ax3.xaxis.grid(True,alpha=0.3)
    ax3.set_ylabel('Predicted Direction ')

    fig.suptitle(details, fontsize=10)

    xtick_dates = pd.date_range(start = df.index[0], end = df.index[-1], freq='3M')
    plt.xticks(xtick_dates, [dtz.strftime('%Y-%m') for dtz in xtick_dates], rotation=88)

    fig.text(0.5, 0.04, 'Quarter Closing Dates', ha='center')

    plt.show()
```

[image: Prediction for GM]